# Angular - display Hebrew(LTR)

Tags: html, angularjs, hebrew

I am trying to display Hebrew text in a `table` via `ng-repeat`, after changing the values in my controller:

```
if(data[i].name == 'Dan'){
    data[i].name = 'דן' // hebrew for Dan
}
```

The result is `פֿפֿפֿפֿפֿ`(format problem I think).
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe your page is not coded in "utf-8", that can help you: http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_utf8.asp

Comment: I am using 'UTF-8' encoding.

Comment: Do you have an error prompted in the console ?

Comment: No, only the text is not in hebrew.

Comment: Can you tell us what happens when you copy/paste 'דן' in the console and click on "enter" ? (the character is well printend or there is an error or something else ?)

Comment: 'SyntexError: Unexpected token' shown in the console.

Comment: I could come from many other parameters,(browser, versions, OS, etc.), i found a previous post about the same problem, maybe it can help you: http://superuser.com/questions/948233/how-to-fix-hebrew-font-in-chrome-browser-after-installing-windows-10